# Modified row spacing in Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have the following markup.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="Truck_Notes">Notes</label>
            <textarea rows="3" class="form-control" id="Truck_Notes" name="Truck.Notes"></textarea>
            <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Truck.Notes" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="/Trucks">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group text-end">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It looked fine in Bootstrap 4. But in Bootstrap 5 there is no spacing between the two rows.

[image]

Bootstrap has always been good about spacing between rows. What is the preferred way in Bootstrap 5 to have appropriate spacing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to use the `my` class from Bootstrap for the top and bottom `margin`. In your example, I added `my-3` for `1rem` of top and bottom `margin` on your `textarea` element.

The reason the spacing is different on B5 is because `form-group`, `form-row`, and `form-inline` classes have been removed in Bootstrap 5: So [Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/) and [Utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/utilities/) are supposed to be used instead. The updated spacing in B5 is actually really useful in numerous instances. Because of that, many of the default classes used for spacing were removed.

Read more about Bootstrap Spacing here - [Bootstrap 5 Spacing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/)

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="Truck_Notes">Notes</label>
            <textarea rows="3" class="form-control my-3" id="Truck_Notes" name="Truck.Notes"></textarea>
            <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Truck.Notes" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="/Trucks">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group text-end">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but are you saying with Bootstrap 5, I need to manually add margins to virtually every row? If that is an improvement, I'm obviously missing something.

Comment: @JonathanWood The reason the spacing is different on B5 is because `form-group`, `form-row`, and `form-inline` classes have been removed in Bootstrap 5: So [Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/) and [Utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/utilities/) are supposed to be used instead. The updated spacing in B5 is actually really useful in numerous instances. Because of that, many of the default classes used for spacing were removed.